# Test Bluetooth on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, macos, bluetooth

I'd really like to start testing my iOS apps Bluetooth capabilities, but have run into a few problems:

I have a device made with a RN-42 module, but it's not the Apple version and I don't have the Apple authentication module at the moment (I ordered it, but shipping from China can take a while). I know what the messages will look like, but can't send them to my iPhone!

I can use the module with my Macbook, but not in the iOS simulator! Apple has taken down all of the documentation related to getting the iOS < 7.0 to use a separate bluetooth dongle, and my efforts have left my 6.1 simulator endlessly spinning on the bluetooth screen.

I'm new to using Bluetooth, so this may be a dumb question...
Is there a way of getting a bluetooth client device (I have a Mac, another iPhone, and an Android tab) to act as a server module that can send (and receive) Bluetooth data to my iPhone?

Client/Server as per [developer.bluetooth.org](https://developer.bluetooth.org/DevelopmentResources/Pages/Introduction-to-Bluetooth-Application-Development.aspx)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure your meaning of "server module". But in CoreBluetooth, you can use CBPeripheralManager to broadcast data to other iOS or Mac apps.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/Reference/CBPeripheralManager.html

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I found a demo for this running on iOS: [KhaosT/CBPeripheralManager-Demo](https://github.com/KhaosT/CBPeripheralManager-Demo)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using standard Bluetooth (i.e. not Bluetooth LE or Bluetooth Smart or whatever you want to call it), you'll need to enroll in the MFI program or work with an MFI certified device (such as a Redpark cable) and use the External Accessories library provided by Apple. If you're using Bluetooth LE, you can use the Core Bluetooth library provided by Apple. If you fall into neither of those cases, sorry, you can't use Bluetooth on iOS.

Comment: Good to know. The RN-42 uses Bluetooth 2.1 (Classic). I have little interest in signing up for the MFi program, I'll probably just start looking for a 'smart' module!

Comment: @ThatGuyRightThere, note that there are limitations on Bluetooth Smart vs regular Bluetooth. It'd be good to look into those limitations and understand them before investing a lot of time in coding as Bluetooth Smart certainly doesn't meet all application's requirements. (i.e. it's slow and it takes some work if you're transferring large amounts of data)

Comment: This is a good point, I had checked the Wiki page but perhaps I will do a little real research before deciding how this will work. I expect the max data rate I will reach is far lower than that of Bluetooth LE; I'll be sending very small packets of data, probably no more than 10 Bytes each.

Comment: @ThatGuyRightThere If you sending anything less than 20 bytes you should be good to go (as long as you don't require more than roughly 0.3 to 2 kBps). Theoretical transfer rates are quicker for the BTLE spec, but iOS devices don't operate at the max speed.